# How would I compare NSDate from my database of type TIMESTAMP?

Tags: sqlite, ios4, timestamp, nsdate, nsdateformatter

In my sqlite database I have a column named datekey of type TIMESTAMP.

How would i match two timestamps ?

I am using this:

```
NSString *Sql =@"SELECT ZTIMESLOT,ZAGENDA1,ZAGENDA2 FROM tbl_agenda where tbl_agenda.ZDATEKEY=%d";

NSString *sqlFormated = [NSString stringWithFormat:Sql,date];
```

where date is of type NSDate.

But as i can see in my database timestamp value for 26 feb is 1298678400 which is correct but when i am trying to match with above source code then date value become 78756944 which is complete wrong for comparison.

Please help

My complete code

```
-(NSMutableArray*)getAgendaDetail:(NSDate*)date
```

{

```
NSMutableArray *DateArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
sqlite3 *database;

@try
{
    DBSettings *dbSettings = [[DBSettings alloc]init];
    [dbSettings checkAndCreateDatabase];
    DatabaseName=dbSettings.DBName;
    DatabasePath=dbSettings.DBPath;
    [dbSettings release];

    if(sqlite3_open([DatabasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
        const char *sqlStatement;
        //NSString *Sql = @"SELECT * FROM song_info where id_song=%d" ;
        NSString *Sql =@"SELECT ZTIMESLOT,ZAGENDA1,ZAGENDA2 FROM tbl_agenda where tbl_agenda.ZDATEKEY=%lu";
        NSString *sqlFormated = [NSString stringWithFormat:Sql,date];
        sqlStatement=[sqlFormated UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
            {
    ---------------------------
```

getting complete wrong value for sqlFormatted as compared to database value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its an unsigned int, the date or the timestamp, you should use %lu, if its an NSTimeInterval you should use %f as an NSTimeInterval is a double.

Comment: Please see my above source code. i have added more info there. Please tell me whats wrong with that ?

Comment: @Tariq- iPHONE Programmer have you tried using %f yet? make a debug logging call that dumps your SQL